# Circular Motion - Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

The motion of a particle on the surface of a right circular cone is defined by the relations R = ht tan$\beta$, $\theta$=2$\pi$t, and z = ht, where $\beta$ is the apex angle of the cone and h is the distance the particle rises in one passage around the cone. Determine the magnitudes of the velocity and acceleration at any time t.

I don't know what I should differentiate between getting the equation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/894aJ.png)

Comment: What are the definitions of the variables?  Is that a zero? ($0=2\pi t$)?  A cone is a three dimensional object, so should you not have an expression involving $\mathbf{R} = \{ x, y, z\}$ or $\mathbf{R} = \{ r\cos \beta, r\sin \beta, z \}$?

Comment: What is the time for one passage around the cone?

Comment: @mjw - $\beta$ is the apex angle of the cone, which is a constant. It cannot be used as the cylindrical coordinate angle. @ MoamenEslam - you can clear up the confusion by using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). In particular, greek letters can generally be entered as their spelled-out names. for example,  `$\beta, \theta$` gives $\beta, \theta$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, Thank you!

Comment: Okay, in any case, if you can find an expression for the position at time $t$, say as a vector, then the velocity will be it's time derivative, and acceleration, the second derivative.  Find these, and take their magnitudes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R=ht\tan\beta$→$\dot{R}=h\tan\beta$→$\ddot{R}=0$ , $\theta=2\pi t$ → $\dot{\theta}=2\pi$ → $\ddot{\theta}=0$ , $Z=ht$ → $\dot{Z}=h$ → $\ddot{Z}=0$

#### $v_R=h\tan\beta$ , $v_{\theta}=2\pi ht\tan\beta$ , $v_Z=h$ → $a_R=-4\pi^2ht\tan\beta$ , $a_{\theta}=4\pi h \tan\beta$ , $a_Z=0$